# React Context is not defined no-undef

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have navigation constant which is an array of objects(web-store mega-nav). I need to use context provider and when I'm trying to use my context it's telling me `NavContext' is not defined  no-undef`.

**NavContext.js**

```js
import { createContext } from 'react'

const navigation = [...] // array of objects

const NavContext = createContext(navigation)

export default NavContext
```

**Nav.js**

```js
import {createContext} from 'react'
import NavContext from './context/NavContext' //added

function Nav() {

    return (
        <NavContext.Provider> //deleted value
        // childrens
        </NavContext.Provider>
    )
}
```

**Sidebar.js**

```js
//then in one of the child I'm trying to call it:

import { useContext } from 'react'
import NavContext from '../context/NavContext' //added

function Sidebar(){
    const nav = useContext(NavContext)

    return (
        {nav.map(...)} // nav is undefined
    )
}
```

Now nav constant is **undefined** when I'm using `useContext`

Comment: I've exported it and then import this context... But why should we use context if I can export any constant and import it without context? I thought that this hook seems like redux store.

Comment: export and import `NavContext`

Comment: NavContext.Provider must have a value attribute. createContext is more useful for reactive variables with deep nesting to avoid prop drilling. For constants I would just export/import.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to export the create context like this

export const NavContext = createContext(navigation)

Then import it into your child component like this

import { NavContext} from "../Nav";

Comment: yep. I've tryed it already, but it makes no sense to use Context, Provider and Consumer...  with such success i can just export my constant and use it there.

Answer (score 3):

//Create a new NavContext.js File.

```js
import React, { createContext, useReducer } from "react";

export const NavContext = createContext();

const initialState = {
}

function reducer(state, action) {
  return { ...state, ...action };
}

export const NavProvider = (props) => {
  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, initialState);
  return (
    <NavContext.Provider value={{ state, dispatch }}>
      {props.children}
    </NavContext.Provider>
  );
};
```

Then in your index.js file.

```js
import { NavProvider} from "./NavContext";

ReactDOM.render(
  <NavProvider>
    <App />
  </NavProvider>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

If that doesnt work idk what will.

Answer (score 1):

Try not to pass any arguments into createContext, then pass navigation into Context provider as prop

```
<Context.Provider value={navigation} />
```

And then get the value using useContext Hook in your consumer component

Answer (score -1):

For my knowledge, you have to import `useContext` like this.

```
import React, { useContext } from 'react'
```

Comment: I've done it already. Too simple. Not the case.